# Responsive triangles on both sides of the element

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I have a project where there will be two triangles, one of each side, as the images below shows, I am having difficulty in, first of all, getting each one on correct side, I have been trying using floats but it is not working.

And then making them align with the white zone irrespective of screen size i.e. responsive.

[image: PROJECT]

```css
#anim {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/rxks29H.jpg");
  background-image: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}
#anim img {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.arrow-left {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 200px;
  border-top: 200px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 200px solid transparent;
  z-index: 3;
  top: 30%;
  border-left: 200px solid green;
}
.arrow-right {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  float: right;
  z-index: 3;
  border-top: 200px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 200px solid transparent;
  top: 30%;
  border-right: 200px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<section id="anim">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ucQ3ZXl.png">


  <div class="arrow-right">
  </div>
  <div class="arrow-left">
  </div>


</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not make the arrows part of the background image to insure that it's always in place no matter the screen size, and then the content in each arrow can be positioned on top an if it moves a little it wont break the background itself. I created the background really fast to illustrate what I mean, feel free to re-create the image yourself if needed.

[image: with arrows part of the image]

to position the text in each arrow change the CSS to this:

`float: left` or `float: right` don't work with `position: absolute` you need to use the `left` and `right` properties.

```css
#anim {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/rxks29H.jpg");
  background-image: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}
#anim img {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.arrow-left {
  padding: 2.5% 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: absolute;
  width: 13%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  top: 36%;
}
.arrow-right {
  padding: 2.5% 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: absolute;
  width: 13%;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  top: 36%;
}
.arrow-right h2 {
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #FFF;
}
.arrow-left h2 {
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<section id="anim">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fbhc4.png">
  <div class="arrow-right">
    <h2>Scouting For Companies</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="arrow-left">
    <h2>Seeking For Ideas</h2>
  </div>


</section>
```

You will need to add some rules for smaller screens and really large ones if you are making the site responsive.

** **Edit** **

I added the animation really quick just to illustrate what you need to do and give you a good head start on it.
Here is a [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/a6uwrdm9/4/).

Comment: But each triangle will have animations on hover, i cant use the triangles as an image, the animation is like this: http://i.imgur.com/2t4decA.png

Comment: You could animate the whole section just fine. once you hover on the arrow area

Comment: can i do it with css ?

Comment: @BugaDroid Yes you can, but you need some Javascript or jQuery to add a class when you click on each arrow. If you need me to show you I can do that.

Comment: Yes, i am bit afraid that this will be hard for me, if you could help me more i would be gratefull.

Comment: Thank you so much, yes it helps. Just one more thing, how can i make the animation to not reset while i am still hovering the content that is hidden ?

Comment: @BugaDroid I made the Hoverable area bigger so it won't reset unless you move the mouse completely out of the whole hidden column now. See the updated JSFIDDLE https://jsfiddle.net/a6uwrdm9/4/

Comment: Hey, i used your code but it still does reset if move the mouse just a little, however that does not happen on the jsfiddle. am i missing something ? Anyway, you already helped and im thankfull for that and sorry if im bothering you.

Comment: I'm not sure why that happens. best of luck.